# How to join items from different Dataframes to one common DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose We have a Dataframe 'A':

```
Id    Name    FavColor    Address
1     John    Black       xyz
2     Mathew  Orange      www
3     Russel  Red         xxx
```

Now I have a case where different datasets comes as to update values in some columns,
for example Let us have DataFrame 'B' :

```
Id    FavColor
1     Red
2     Black
```

and DataFrame 'C' :

```
Id    Address
1     aaa
3     bbb
```

now in this case updates 'B' and 'C' needs to be merged in 'A',
I tried merging 'B' and 'C' first and then merging it to 'A', but when I merge 'B' and 'C' I get :

```
Id    FavColor    Address
1     Red         aaa
2     Black       null
3     null        bbb
```

and if I merge this with 'A' it will be wrong as Address of Id=2 will become null and FavColor of Id=3 will become null. How can I merge the coming updated Data with 'A' and the coming data may have new attribute in that case it should show null for the items which do not have value for that attribute in 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

Try merging data by using left join and getting only updated rows. Below code merges A and B, then you can merge their result with C in the same way.

```
scala> A.join(B, A("Id") === B("Id"), "left").
     | withColumn("merged", when(B("FavColor").isNotNull, B("FavColor")).otherwise(A("FavColor"))).
     | drop(B("FavColor")).drop(A("FavColor")).drop(B("Id")).
     | withColumnRenamed("merged", "FavColor").show()

+---+------+-------+--------+
| Id|  Name|Address|FavColor|
+---+------+-------+--------+
|  1|  John|    xyz|     Red|
|  2|Mathew|    www|   Black|
|  3|Russel|    xxx|     Red|
+---+------+-------+--------+
```